# Select-Object returns the first result as my column name instead of as a result

Tags: powershell

The following script checks mailboxes in a specified OU for users with the default permission set to Owner. I have tried everything to add the column "Name" from the variable `$Mailbox` to the Select-Object results in the following code. The result will add a column header with the first results name as the header. If there are multiple results the first name found will be the column header with the column blank for the others. Is there a way to add the "Name" column from the variable `$Mailbox` to the Select-Object results?

```
$AllMailBox = Get-Mailbox   -OrganizationalUnit "XXXXXXXXXX.com/DomainUsers/Users" -resultsize unlimited
ForEach ($MailBox in $AllMailbox) {Get-mailboxfolderpermission $Mailbox | Where-object {$_.User -match "Default" -AND $_.AccessRights -match "Owner"} | Select-Object  Identity, AccessRights, $MailBox.Name}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of

```
Select-Object  Identity, AccessRights, $MailBox.Name}
```

Add this

```
Select-Object  Identity, AccessRights, @{l="Name";e={$MailBox.Name}}}
```

where `l` stands for Label and `e` stands for Expression.

You can read more about custom tables here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What if I don't know the original column names up front, ie the result of a SELECT * type query?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The column names are fixed so you can just look them up beforehand when writing the script. Or set them as a variable and allow the runner of the script to input the variable in some kind of modal window or form.

Answer (score 2):

`$MailBox.Name` lives in outer scope.  It isn't a valid property of item returned from `Get-mailboxfolderpermission`.

You can use calculated property in `Select-Object` to add additional data to the result:

```
{Get-mailboxfolderpermission $Mailbox | Where-object {$_.User -match "Default" -AND $_.AccessRights -match "Owner"} | Select-Object  Identity, AccessRights,@{Name="Name"; Expression={$MailBox.Name}}
```

Calculated property is declared by hash table with keys:

- `Name` — the name of the property
- `Expression` — script block that returns a value

See "EXAMPLE 4" [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) for another example of calculated property.